# Can a polynomial with positive coefficients intersect the curve $\frac 1 {(1-x)(1+qx)}$ more than twice?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials

Suppose you have a polynomial, $p(x)=p_0+p_1x+\ldots+p_nx^n$ such that $p_i>0$. Can this polynomial intersect $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1+qx)}$ twice in the interval $\left(\frac{q-1}{2q},1\right)$ where $q>2$?
I feel that after $\frac{q-1}{2q}$, the function $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1+qx)}$ will grow too fast and the polynomial cannot beat it so it is going to have even number of roots of course. However, I could not prove that it can have at most two roots.

Comment: Since the $p_i$ and $\frac{q-1}{2q}$ are positive, the condition $p\left(\frac{q-1}{2q}\right)>0$ is automatically satisfied.

Comment: Yes, now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be more than two intersections.

For example (the particular numbers are not critical in what follows):

Consider the polynomial $0.5+x+100x^{40}$.

This intersects the other curve at (roughly) $0.26,0.76,0.89 $ and $0.998$. This has three roots in the region of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
Let $f_q(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1+qx)}$.
Consider $q=10$.
Then $\frac{q-1}{2q}=\frac{9}{20}<0.5<0.6$.
Also, $f_q(0.5)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $f_q(0.6)=\frac{5}{14}$.
Let $p(x)$ be the line that passes through $(0.5,f_q(0.5))$ and $(0.6,f_q(0.6))$.
Then $p(x)=\frac{5}{21}x+\frac{3}{14}$.
Your conditions are satisfied.

---

Actually, the above method can be generalized.
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function that is continuously differentiable on some interval $I=(a,a+\delta)$, where $\delta>0$.
Suppose $f(a)>0$, $f'$ is strictly increasing on $I$,
and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x)=0$.
Then there always exist $b_1<b_2\in (a,a+\delta)$ such that
the line that passes through $(b_1,f(b_1))$ and $(b_2,f(b_2))$
has a positive slope that can be arbitrarily small.
Since $f(a)>0$,
we can always force the line to have a positive $y$-intercept.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to ask whether it can intersect more than twice. I have edited the question.